# conditional search

Tags: filters, search

I am looking for help with a conditional search based on four categories/taxonomies; countries/regions/type/no of bedrooms. What I am after is a dropdown search function that when I select a specific country, only regions in that country would appear in the region dropdown and in the type drop down, only types available in that particular region would be listed. I am obviously prepared to pay a fee for customisation.
JOHN

Answer (score 1):

solution 1:

1. this can be done by adding the drop down menu to the search form.eg cat_slct
2. create a search template if its not exist in your theme.
3. add an if statement at the top of the page and directly after `get_header();`

-

```
if(isset($_POST['cat_slct'])){

    //make the query using the name of the categoty you'v just received via $_POST[].
    //or search within the database if necessary using the $wpdb object,it helps a lot.
}

}else{

    //the search page as its without modifying.
    //just you have to add the closing else tag before the get_footer(); 

}//right before the get_footer()
```

---

solution 2:

1. same as solution 1 but this time you'll create a page template and call it custom_search.
2. now go ahead and create a page that uses the custom_page template..eg name it search_cats.
3. tha different here is that you'll set the action of your targeted search forms to this page.
4. same as before: get the posted data and insert it into the query then do the regular loop.